# Sorting RecursiveArrayIterator

Tags: php, iterator, spl

I have the following code:

```
$itemA = array(
        'token' => "SOME_TOKEN",
        'default' => "DEFAULT A",
        'order' => 5
);
$itemB = array(
        'token' => "SOME__OTHER_TOKEN",
        'default' => "DEFAULT B",
        'order' => 2
);
$collection = new \RecursiveArrayIterator(array($itemA, $itemB));
$collection->uasort(function( $a, $b ) {
        if ($a['order'] === $b['order']) {
                return 0;
        }
        return ($a['order'] < $b['order']) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Which was supposed to sort the `$collection` internal array. In fact, it does, because when I `var_dump($collection)` - I can see that `$itemB` is the first (as it has lower order).

BUT - when I start iterating items from `$collection`, I am still getting `$itemA` as the first element.

Unfortunately, [documentation](http://php.net/manual/ru/arrayiterator.uasort.php) doesn't have any mentions of the issue, which is why I would like to know if this is a bug or I missed something?

**UPDATE**

The iteration code:

```
while ($collection->valid())
{
    $current = $collection->current(); // current is already wrong :(
    ... do stuff ...
    $collection->next();
}
```

My php version is 5.3.10, in case this is relevant.
Gist with a [failing unit test](https://gist.github.com/t1gor/3674e78251790362af00).

Comment: Works here. Please show how you iterate the collection. (BTW, your compare func can be simply `return $a['order'] - $b['order'];`)

Comment: @georg, added iteration code. But simply calling current would be enough, actually. I've created a gist for more details: https://gist.github.com/t1gor/3674e78251790362af00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `uasort` affects the internal `current` pointer of the iterator, so you need `$collection->rewind()` before the loop. Better yet, instead of `while(valid)`, use `foreach`, which  automatically rewinds it for you:

```
$collection = new \RecursiveArrayIterator(...);
$collection->uasort(function( $a, $b ) {
    return $a['order'] - $b['order'];
});

foreach($collection as $item)
    print_r($item); // all fine
```